# Insert a Google Map inside a Jquery Tab

Tags: jquery-ui, google-maps

I insert a simply Google Map into my page:
http://www.albertanglada.es/index.php?page=test

But if i insert it into a tab (Ubicacion)
http://www.albertanglada.es/index.php?page=anunciantes&anunciantes=nuevo-estilo
http://www.albertanglada.es/index.php?page=anunciantes&anunciantes=nuevo-estilo#mapa

The mapa doesnt show well, any ideas?

Comment: The pages you linked are asking for username/password.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see your page - read this on the jquery ui tabs page regarding google map display, perhaps it will help.

[Jquery ui google maps info](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...my_slider.2C_Google_Map.2C_sIFR_etc._not_work_when_placed_in_a_hidden_.28inactive.29_tab.3F)

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#inf_anunciante > ul').bind('tabsshow', function(event, ui) {
    alert('je');
    if (ui.panel.id == "mapa") {
      alert('jo');  
      resizeMap();
    }
  });       <div id="inf_anunciante"> <!-- begin jquery tabbed latest reviews -->
        <ul class="tabnav ui-tabs-nav">  <!-- tab headers link to tab areas below -->
          <li class="ui-tabs-selected"><a href="#one">Descripción</a></li>     
          <li class=""><a href="#mapa">Ubicación</a></li>   still you cant view my code?

Comment: mira que eres guarro, qué haces poniendo ahí codigo?

Comment: ya es muy sick era para no responderme a mi mismo xD